# Core-Bluetooth: Is Core-Bluetooth appending a line feed after each package?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is `Core-Bluetooth` appending automatically a `line feed after each package`, which is sent? Is there any way to disable it?

my writeValue looks like this:

```
NSString * test = command;
            NSData *data = [test dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [_discoveredPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic: hr_characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I´ve a sniffer which monitor the sent commands and the reply of the peripheral. I need to send commands(String). Is it better to use writeValue or updateValue??

greetings

Comment: Can you explain more this: appending automatically a line feed after each package?

Comment: Core-Bluetooth won't add anything to the data you are sending. What does the String `test` contain?  Also, you probably want NSASCIIStringEncoding, not UTF8 encoding

Comment: ok its a problem of my peripheral again. Whats the advantage of NSASCIIStringEncoding?